# How to define the time of removing of user from custom audience automatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

If I add user to custom audience through API calls - can I set time of automatical removal user from the custom audience?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't offer any automatic mechanisms like that. You'll need to remove them explicitly.

Comment: Note that you can use Web Custom Audiences to define lookback windows, e.g. people who made a Purchase within the last 7 days. You can use pixels or App Events as the basis for these audiences. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api/websites